# Schedule job with dynamic Output To Host File System in JasperServer

Tags: jasperserver

Is there possibility to create a scheduled job that have dynamic Output To Host File System?
For example I wanna create a job that generate report evry weak and I wanna to have Output in a folder that is created for reports generated in specific date.

Comment: `job that have dynamic Output` - What do you mean?

Comment: when you are creating scheduled job there are output options. There is "Output destination" > "Output To Host File System". Now I wana create job that runs every monday for example and every time i want to output will be different first week "/reports/week1" next run should be "/reports/week2" etc